# Controlling pygame animation through text input

Tags: python, pygame

I need to create a fighting game that gives prompts and accepts input through text, such as a raw input and then performs the animation, while still have the characters animated, e.g. moving back and forth in a ready to fight stance. How would I go about this?

Comment: I suggest using Threads if you need parallel animation and text input.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa... No need for threads and parallel animation... I'm assuming the OP is meaning something Fire Emblem style?

Comment: You need threads if you want the characters having a idle animation while typing.

Comment: @FredrikRosenqvist Not really, please note my answer. In this situation, the only real NEED is if you want an idle animation while writing or reading information, or accessing server. With a game loop in pygame, you can still type and handle input while keeping the main game loop going

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is not going to be your typical answer. StackOverflow is to help after all that you can do on your part when you are stuck, it's not meant as a place to come for code, but since I'm assuming other people new to programming will also be confused on things such as these. So I'm going to write some code, and some psuedo code, just so that you get the just of what you would do in such a scenario.

```
# TODO put your imports up here

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400)) # 2/3 aspect ratio
FPS = 40 # Set to your own Frames per second

class Animator:
    def __init__(self, surface, rows, cols, time_between_frames, on_finish):
        self.images = []
        self.current_image = 0
        self.time_between_frames = time_between_frames # time animator waits before changing surface
        self.current_time # tracks time for frames to change
        self.on_finish = on_finish # function to call when animation finishes
        surf_width = (surface.get_width() / cols) # calculate width
        surf_height = (surface.get_height() / rows) # calculate height
        for x in range(cols):
            for y in range(rows):
                surf = pygame.Surface(surface.get_size()) # temp surface
                from_rect = pygame.Rect(x * surf_width, y * surf_height, surf_width, surf_height) # rect to blit from
                surf.blit(surface, (0,0), from_rect) # draw to temp surface
                self.images.append(surf) # add temp surface to the images list

    def update(delta):
        self.current_time += delta # update current time
        if (self.current_time >= self.time_between_frames): # if time to switch surfaces
            self.current_time -= self.time_between_frames # take away time from current time
            self.current_image += 1 # change image
            if self.current_image >= len(self.images): # if current image would throw an out of bounds exception
                self.current_image = 0 # reset the current image to the first

    def get_frame(self):
        return self.images[self.current_image]

class Player:
    resting = 0
    abdomenKick = 1
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.action = Player.resting
        self.restingAnimation = Animation(pygame.image.load("resting.png"), 2, 3, 500)
        self.abdomenKickAnimation = Animation(pygame.image.load("abdomenKick.png"), 4, 6, 50)
        self.currentAnimation = self.restingAnimation

    def update(self, delta):
        self.currentAnimation.update(delta)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.currentAnimation.get_frame(), (self.x, self.y))

    def abdomenKick(self):
        self.currentAnimation = self.restingAnimation

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player()

    def update(self, delta):
        self.player.update(delta)

    def draw_screen(self, surface):
        self.player.draw(surface)

def gameLoop():
    game = Game()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == A:
                    game.player.abdomenKick() #Or whatever move you have

        game.update(clock.get_rawtime())
        game.draw_screen()

        clock.tick(FPS)
```

So here is just a brief showcase you can call it of what this might look like.